# When using DateTimeFormatInfo, Which Culture is used in generating the result string?

Tags: .net, calendar, cultureinfo, iformatprovider, datetimeformatinfo

When I use `DateTimeFormatInfo`, Sometimes current thread culture is used for generating the result string and some times the culture I get `DateTimeFormatInfo` from it. Also there is situation where Invariant Culture is used. What is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we build a `DateTimeFormatInfo`, it always specify the format string. If we pass it as `IFormatProvider` to the `ToString` or `string.Format` methods, its calendar used for displaying datetime too (date elements calculated by that calendar) but if we do not pass it, current culture info passed as `IFormatProvider` by default and so current culture calendar used for calculation of date time elements. In Four special case, despite every culture you used for creating `DateTimeFormatInfo` or every `IFormatProvider` you pass to those methods, Invariant Culture and Invariant Calendar used. These are: `"O" (or "o"), "R" (or "r"), "s", and "u"`. The following example show some example:

```
 static void ChangeStandardFormatStringAssociation()
    {
        // Build a writable instance of DateTimeFormatInfo which is get from writable CultureInfo (for example using ctor or using CreateSpecificCulture)
        var formatInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").DateTimeFormat; // d standard format associated by "MM-dd-yyyy" in short Date for en-US but we want to change it to "dd-MM-yyyy"
        Console.WriteLine($"Culture which FormatInfo built from:en-US (This can not calculate from FormatInfo)");
        Console.WriteLine($"FormatInfo is readonly?{formatInfo.IsReadOnly}");
        Console.WriteLine(formatInfo.ShortDatePattern);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
        // What is current culture?
        Console.WriteLine($"Current Culture is :{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name}");
        var dt = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        Console.WriteLine($"{dt:d} (Current Culture)");// consider that if we do not specify formatInfo it uses the current culture 
        Console.WriteLine($"{dt.ToString("d", formatInfo)} (Culture which formatInfo built from)"); // It uses Calendar related to that cultureInfo and then calculate parts of given date in that culture and shows them
        Console.WriteLine($"{dt.ToString(formatInfo.ShortDatePattern)} (Culture which formatinfo build from Get the format string and calendar properties from current culture is used)");
        Console.WriteLine($"{dt.ToString("r", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)} (Invariant Culture and Invariant Calendar used Even we pass other culture info)");
        Console.WriteLine($"{dt.ToString(formatInfo.ShortDatePattern, formatInfo)} (Culture which formatinfo build from Get the format string and calendar properties from that culture is also used since we set it as format provider)");

    }
```